# How to add the same object to a polymorphic array but be able to make changes to a duplicate version of that object?

Tags: java, android, arrays

So I have a polymorphic Array List of type Card

```
private ArrayList<Card> compSciDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

And I have an array of Minion cards which is a sub class of Card.

```
 Card compSciSpell[] = new Card[3];
 compSciSpell[0] = new SpellCard(2, "Virus", Card.Subject.COMPUTER_SCIENCE, Card.Rarity.COMMON, "Damage defense row by 2", SpellCard.Ability.DAMAGE, 60, CONST_Y, "VirusSpell", this);
 compSciSpell[1] = new SpellCard(3, "Bug", Card.Subject.COMPUTER_SCIENCE, Card.Rarity.COMMON, "Remove all minion cards", SpellCard.Ability.DECREASE_ROW, 100, CONST_Y, "BugSpell", this);
 compSciSpell[2] = new SpellCard(4, "Ram", Card.Subject.COMPUTER_SCIENCE, Card.Rarity.COMMON, "Duplicate your strength cards", SpellCard.Ability.NO_ABILITY, 300, CONST_Y, "RamSpell", this);
```

I then add these cards to my ArrayList randomly using a for loop. (A card is added before this for loop also)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(3);
    compSciDeck.add(i+1, compSciSpell[index]);
}
```

The problem I am having is that my random assignment shows in my ArrayList I have 5 objects and some duplicates of the same object. This is what I want, however, the duplicates have the same place in memory as each other.

Therefore when I want to make a change to only one of their values, it changes the other duplicate object. 
How do I make it so I can alter a specific duplicate and not make a change to another?

Comment: The objects in java are mutable, you are acceding to a reference. if you modify one the other will change too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to clone the `Card` object before adding it to the `compSciDeck` collection.

Something along the lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(3);
    compSciDeck.add(i+1, compSciSpell[index].clone());
}
```

If you can avoid the clone method and add a copy constructor that will be better. Regarding copy constructor versus clone, check [this interview with Joshua Bloch](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Here is a sample of a copy constructor:

```
public static class SpellCard {

    private int index;

    private String name;

    ... // more fields here

    public SpellCard(int index, String name) {
        this.index = index;
        this.name = name;
        ... // more fields here.
    }

    // Copy constructor
    public SpellCard(SpellCard other) {
        this.index = other.index;
        this.name = other.name;
        ... // more fields here
    }
}
```

With the copy constructor you could then re-write your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(3);
    compSciDeck.add(i+1, new SpellCard((SpellCard) compSciSpell[index]));
}
```

Comment: as I have an inheritance hierarchy, how would I do this I get the error "There is no default constructor available"

Comment: You could add one default constructor together with the existing constructors. Something like `public SpellCard() {}`